# Capturing NSEvent to add modifier Issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent

I'm trying to programmatically hold down the option key for my user in a cocoa app.

For the life of me I can't seem to grab the NSEVENT modify it and re-post it.  I still want to capture the MouseDown event because I use the location - I've been trying to grab the event and add the modifier flag to it but it doesn't seem to work.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've done:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    if(!(theEvent.modifierFlags == NSAlternateKeyMask)){

        NSEvent *newEvent = [NSEvent keyEventWithType:
                                      theEvent.type
                                      location:theEvent.locationInWindow 
                                      modifierFlags:NSAlternateKeyMask 
                                      timestamp:theEvent.timestamp 
                                      windowNumber:theEvent.windowNumber 
                                      context:theEvent.context 
                                      characters:@"" 
                                     charactersIgnoringModifiers:@"" 
                                     isARepeat:YES 
                                     keyCode:0];
           [super mouseDown:newEvent];
    }   
}
```

I've also tried variations of this with CGPostEvent- but It never seems to work either.  Apparently posting only a modifier flag is more difficult than it looks.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of holding down the option key, i.e., what other piece of code is going to behave differently and how will it detect the state of the option key?  If the other code is using `CGEventSourceFlagsState` to check modifier key state, I don't think messing with `NSEvent`s is going to fool it.  (By the way, saying `isARepeat:YES` looks wrong.)

Comment: Im trying to simulate the selection capability built into pdfkit - when option is selected but without having the user hold option.

Comment: I edited it for clarity - removing cgeventsourceflagsstate

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this code-

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    if(!(theEvent.modifierFlags == NSAlternateKeyMask)){

        [super mouseDown:[self createNewEvent:theEvent]];
    }
    else {
        [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    }
}

- (NSEvent *)createNewEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
       NSEvent *newEvent = [NSEvent
                         keyEventWithType:NSKeyDown
                         location:theEvent.locationInWindow
                         modifierFlags:NSAlternateKeyMask
                         timestamp:theEvent.timestamp
                         windowNumber:theEvent.windowNumber
                         context:theEvent.context
                         characters:@""
                         charactersIgnoringModifiers:@""
                         isARepeat:NO
                         keyCode:0];
    return newEvent;
}
```